# How can form fields be rendered manually in django-bootstrap

Tags: django, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I have django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus set up in my app. Upon completion, I noticed that my form fields are stacked on rows [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIDep.png) whereas I would love to manually render some of the fields on the same row. Although I know the reason for that is because the form is rendered using `{% bootstrap_form form %}`

Here is my rendered template code snippet below.

```
{% extends 'accounts/no_header_footer.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% load bootstrap4 %}
{% bootstrap_css %}
{% bootstrap_javascript jquery='full' %}
{{ form.media }}

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div class="profile-create-form-container">
    <form class="profile-create-form" data-certificates-url="{% url 'ajax_load_certificates' %}"
          data-grades-url="{% url 'ajax_load_grades' %}"
          data-relationships-url="{% url 'ajax_load_relationships' %}" data-states-url="{% url 'ajax_load_states' %}"
          enctype="multipart/form-data"
          id="ProfileCreateForm"
          method="POST" runat="server">

        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class="form-group text-center">
                <span class="navbar-brand">
                    <img alt="..." height="40px" src="..." width="40px">
                    Basic Information
                </span>
        </fieldset>
        {% bootstrap_form form %}

        <div class="container">
            <div class="text-center">
                <button class="btn btn-dark" type="submit">
                    <i class="fa fa-save"></i> Save and Continue
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

The question I have is, is it possible to render each form field manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by using `{% bootstrap_field field %}` as explained in this [doc](https://django-bootstrap3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templatetags.html#bootstrap-field)